# When i run the grunt requirejs task, i get the following error : **ReferenceError : window is not defined**

Tags: gruntjs, r.js

When i run the grunt requirejs task, i get the following error :
**ReferenceError : window is not defined**

Here is my grunt file :

```
 requirejs: {
        default: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: 'someurl',
                mainConfigFile: "mainconfig.js",
                dir: 'blah blah',
                skipDirOptimize: true, 
                keepBuildDir: true, 
                wrap: false,
                useStrict: false,
                modules: [
                    { name: 'myMainModule' }
                ],
                uglify: false,
                optimize: 'none',
                exclude : ['Text']
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is being raised at the text plugin's execution. I have tried almost all recomendations that are out there. None has worked. I added the exclude line to the build config but did not work either. I tried to use "text : "empty:" but that wont work either coz the loader plugin has to get executed and be avaialable. This has wasted almost 2 days!!
I even emptied the text.js plugin and instead kept an empty load function within it, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try adding 'text': '<path>/<to>/<text-plugin>' to paths {}

Comment: Can you link us to the "Text" plugin? There may be an issue that file that we can discover.

Comment: @fernando , I added what you said but still not working. path : {"text" : "PATH_TO_TEXT_JS"}

Comment: @jakerella , You can find the plugin here : https://github.com/requirejs/text/blob/master/text.js

Comment: I'm starting to think that there might be an issue with the requirejs library itself when it runs under r.js executing a plugin. Its very frustrating as there is no way to even debug this thing. I tried "grunt debug requirejs" but still the debugger gets detached as soon as the error comes up and the window reference error comes up without line numbers just telling that window is not defined while running "text.js"!

Comment: @James I am using https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs plugin and r.js & require version is 2.1.6. Further text plugin version is 2.0.10. It's been used in my current project and works fine

Comment: @fernando Are you able to send me a link to your files so i can update mine to exactly mimic yours please? My requirejs is 2.0.6 and my text plugin is 2.0.3... Also do you think you can send me your config too? I'd really appreciate it. (Cant seem to be able to find those specific file versions)

Comment: @James go to https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs and by selecting the correct tag you can download the files